# Objective-C: Change tracks in player

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have 2 tracks `sound1`, `sound2` and 2 `viewControllers`. When I launch my app in `viewController1` `sound1` start playing. Next I go in `viewController2` and I want to change track in player on button click. But then I click on button tracks mixed. How can I change track on button click correctly?

**viewController1**

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"sound1"];
 NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
 _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
 _player.numberOfLoops = 0;
 [_player play];
```

**viewController2**

```
_paths5 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                     _documentsDirectory5 = [_paths5 objectAtIndex:0];
                     _filePath5 = [_documentsDirectory5 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound2.mp3"];
                     _fileExists5 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_filePath5 isDirectory:false];

                     NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_filePath5];
                     _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
                     _player.numberOfLoops = 0;
                     [_player play];
```

Comment: In `viewWillDisappear` of `viewController1` you could stop the sound. The issue is that `_player` in `viewController1` or `viewController2` aren't the same. There is no "playlist".

Comment: How create playlist?

Answer (score 0):

Just stop your player like,

```
  [_player stop];
```

when your first `viewcontroller` is disappeared(i.e. in `viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear`).

And in your `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidload` of second `viewController` play the second sound file. that's it.

Now if you go back to first viewcontroller and you want to stop sound of second VC then in `viewDidDidappear or viewWillDisappear` of second VC you can stop sound like,

```
  [_player stop];
```

and can play again in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` of first VC.

You can manage your stuff like this way.

Comment: Can I stop first sound form viewController1 in second viewController2?

Comment: if you want to do that then you should send that player to second viewcontroller from `prepareForSegue` or other way and than you can stop by calling `stop` method on that object

Comment: How to do it with prepareForSegue? Could you give me code example?

Comment: are you using segue to go to second viewcontroller? if not then hows you goes to second VC from first?

Comment: I use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

Comment: then in VC2.h make property of `AVPlayer *player` and in `prepareforsegue` do something like, `secondVC.player = _player;` and `secondVC` is instance of second VC which should be done like `SecondViewController *secondVC =  [segue destinationViewController];`